# How to fix page ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk 0 failed.in nuxtjs + heroku?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering, vee-validate

[image]I have created an app with nuxtjs and vee-validate and deployed to heroku but in local(nuxt build and nuxt start in local machine) when i press login button validation by vee-validate happening and everything fine but in heroku app, when pressing login button entire page refreshes and also "?" appended at the end of URL for example:- login to login? when login button clicked.help me in identifying this issue.thanks
seems like js not running.

Comment: ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk 0 failed. in console

Comment: https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/742 if you find the solution on this link.

Comment: Thanks, @mhdnp1234.sometimes problem was due to AdBlock extensions and for some pages, I changed route name to lowercase.

Comment: The same error happened to me using a Service Worker that cached resources. I'd also get 404s if, for whatever reason, the cached HTML page was used and that page tried to load other resources with a hash in their URL over the network but those URLs didn't exist anymore (eg because their hash has changed).

Comment: @FrancescRosas, Thanks . Yeah service worker also part of the issue i think. (for our our case we had a page called UserProfile.vue and changed to userProfile.vue and issue was solved .....) and also updated nuxt version to latest

Comment: I see @sudhakar. I'd bet you were developing on a typically case-insensitive file system OS (Mac/Win) but deploying to a case-sensitive one (Linux).

Comment: @sudhakarselva, you saved my day! AdBlock is the issue!

Answer (score 6):

Probably not the case for most people, but this was caused by an ad blocker for me. I disabled for my site, reloaded page, and all was well. Hope this saves someone else time.
Found hint to this way down in https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/742

Comment: Yeah, had same problem for apex chart component, components was not loading bcuz of adblocker